# tableviewcell height and frame size?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview cell that I am trying to attach an AVPlayer to.

- create cells from cellforrowatindexpath
- set height for row =8 to be 200 in heightforrowatindexpath, other rows use default height
- in cellforrowsatindexpath, if row == 8, call customCell method, which creates avplayer and attaches to the cellview.contentview. I get the cellView by calling cellforrowatindexpath:row8

However when I get the cell to be customized for row 8, the size of the cell is 0 0 0 0. as a result I could not attach the avplayer view to the cell.

here is the console log, notice that the cell size is not zero when created, but returned zero in customCellView. Any idea?

```
heightforrowatindexpath: row = 8, height = 200.000000
cellForRowAtIndexPath: row=8
cell.contentView.frame = {{0, 0}, {320, 199.5}}, cell.frame = {{0, 352}, {320, 200}}
customCellView: customCell.contentView.frame ={{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, textlabel = (null)
customCell.frame ={{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
heightforrowatindexpath: row = 8, height = 200.000000
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that create the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you implement this method?

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can specify the size for each item at a specific indexPath. That could be the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I made a mistake in my code.

I called customCell in cellforrowatIndexpath, which in turn called cellforrowatindexpath to get the cell to be customized in the first place. It seems that cellforrowatindexpath returns nil for the inner call in this case. One either have to customize the cell in cellforrowatindexpath, or pass on the *cell to customizeCell. I used the latter approach.